# jQuery script not working on Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I got this script http://jsfiddle.net/j999y/2878/

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $( ".myelement" ).click(function() {     
         $('.another-element p').toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Injected into my Drupal site via [JS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) module and when you click Toggle it hides/shows the element, it works on JSFiddle, but not on Drupal?

I thought, maybe JS Injector is the problem, so I ran another simple test e.g.

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#buttons').offset().top }, 1000);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

And it works just fine!

Why the toggle script not working?

(I posted this on Drupal answers, they put it on Hold for offtopic and directed to here)

Comment: Could you add some `console.debug('click!');` inside your click handler to determine whether it's called just once or not?

Comment: @Styx hello, it does print out the message `click!
js_injector_3.js:5:10
TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function
[Learn More]
jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:24188
click!`

Comment: @Styx apparently its working if you use only `.toggle()` any idea how to add the sliding animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `context` while querying DOM. Also, using `.once()` will ensure that your click handler is attached (thus, running) just once:

```
attach: function(context, settings) {
  $(".myelement", context).once('click-slide-toggle').click(function() {
     $('.another-element p', context).toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
  });
}
```